# Android Search Activity and android:launchMode="singleTop"

Tags: android, searchview, android-searchmanager, android-search

I have a single activity in my app that uses a SearchView to search (see manifest-- the search intent is intercepted).
However, when I press search, nothing happens.  The activity never re-starts itself.  So, I removed android:launchMode="singleTop" from my activity and then it started re-starting itself and "working."  However, it is preferable to have singleTop for me so that the activity only has one instance.  Why is this not working when I have singleTop?

```
<activity
        android:name="com.brianco.andypedia.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: I apologize that I can't remember how I solved this, but, if I had to guess, I would say trying overriding onNewIntent() in your Activity.  I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers your question, but [this page](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-action-views/) shows a simple searchview example with `ActionBar` Compat (it is the new google library compatible for the old Android versions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your search intent on [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) besides `onCreate`.